Remove outdoor photocell and put a Lutron casita dimmer
So I have multiple outdoor eve lights. The lights have a LED module and I looked up the model number. They are dimmable. They are way too bright.
Presently lights go on and off with a Photocell - there are no other switches.
I want to put a Lutron Caseta dimmer so I can dim the lights.
What is easiest? Remove photocell and put dimmer in same spot? Can I do that?
Add dimmer somewhere else? Three wires on the back of the photocell are Red, Black, White. Where how do I add?

To help us help you help yourself: tell us what you have tried and what research you have done.  Include pix and/or sketch.  Provide links to products (there are a lot of Caseta dimmers - and by the way, do spell it right because details matter).  see https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

What make and model are these lights?

Seagull Lighting 6” traverse model 14701SC
